# SQLException: You can't specify target table 'p' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a small trigger for my DB, but I'm getting the error:

SQLException: You can't specify target table 'p' for update in FROM clause

The query I'm using is:

```
create trigger CheckVendibilitaPP 
after update on hotel
for each row
    if (old.IN_VENDITA=true and new.IN_VENDITA=false) then
    update pacchettopreconfigurato as p 
    set IN_VENDITA=false
    where p.id_pp in (select p2.id_pp
                      from pacchettopreconfigurato as p2 join hotel as h on p2.DESTINAZIONE_PACCHETTO = h.LUOGO
                      where h.id = new.id)
                 and (select count(*)
                      from pacchettopreconfigurato as p3 join hotel as h2 on p3.DESTINAZIONE_PACCHETTO = h2.LUOGO
                      where p3.id_pp = p.id_pp) > 0;
end if;;
```

I saw some answers to symilar questions and tried some of the techniques shown there, but none of those was effective. Wrapping the first part of the query in a "SELECT id_pp FROM (select...) AS c" block, but that wasn't working either.

How should I rewrite the query so for it to stop throwing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the other answers, the solution was to break the where clause in sub-parts.
The need for parameters to be used in the sub-queries led me to write two Boolean functions taking parameters `p.id_pp, new.id` and `p.id_pp` respectively.
The where clause thus became a simple `func_1(p.id_pp,new.id) and func_2(p.id_pp)`

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL docs say that:

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in
>   a subquery

See second to last line [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

What you could do is run the two sub-queries separately, putting their results into variables. Then substitute the variable for the suq-queries in the UPDATE statement.

Comment: You cannot do this: "... from pacchettopreconfigurato as p2 join" .. you just specified table in FROM clause, as the error says

Comment: sub-queries can't take parameters AFAIK, so what I did was use two boolean functions and then and-ing them together in the where clause of the update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use mysql so I don't know if it allows you to use an alias in an update clause, but for those database engines that do, the syntax is:

```
update t
set this = that
from table t join othertable tt on whatever
etc
```